# Is it possible to do a 'normalized' dense_rank() in hive?

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, hive, training-data

I have a consumer table like so.

```
consumer | product | quantity
-------- | ------- | --------
a        | x       | 3
a        | y       | 4
a        | z       | 1
b        | x       | 3
b        | y       | 5
c        | x       | 4
```

What I want is a 'normalized' rank assigned to each consumer so that I can split the table easily for testing and training. I used the dense_rank() in hive, so I got the below table.

```
rank | consumer | product | quantity
---- | -------- | ------- | --------
1    | a        | x       | 3
1    | a        | y       | 4
1    | a        | z       | 1
2    | b        | x       | 3
2    | b        | y       | 5
3    | c        | x       | 4
```

This is well and good, but I want to scale this to use with any number of consumers, so I would ideally like the range of ranks between 0 and 1, like so.

```
rank | consumer | product | quantity
---- | -------- | ------- | --------
0.33 | a        | x       | 3
0.33 | a        | y       | 4
0.33 | a        | z       | 1
0.67 | b        | x       | 3
0.67 | b        | y       | 5
1    | c        | x       | 4
```

This way, I'd always know what the range of ranks is, and can split the data in a standard way (rank <= 0.7 training, and rank > 0.7 testing)

Is there a way to achieve this in hive?

Or, is there a different and better approach to my original issue of splitting the data?

I tried to do a `select * where rank < 0.7*max(rank)`, but hive says the MAX UDAF is not yet available in where clause.

Comment: UDAF will never be available in the `where` clause. It does not match the SQL language definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**percent_rank**

```
select  percent_rank() over (order by consumer) as pr
       ,* 

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+-----+----------+---------+----------+
| pr  | consumer | product | quantity |
+-----+----------+---------+----------+
| 0.0 | a        | z       |        1 |
| 0.0 | a        | y       |        4 |
| 0.0 | a        | x       |        3 |
| 0.6 | b        | y       |        5 |
| 0.6 | b        | x       |        3 |
| 1.0 | c        | x       |        4 |
+-----+----------+---------+----------+
```

---

For filtering you'll need a sub-query / CTE

```
select  *

from   (select  percent_rank() over (order by consumer) as pr
               ,* 

        from    mytable
        ) t

where   pr <= ...
;
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you!